# Choosing which rows to sum and average in either SSRS or SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, average, ssrs-2012

```
ROW        column 1         column 2
1             A                  1
2             A                  1
3             A                  3
4             A                  1
5             A                  2
6             B                  1
7             B                  3
8             B                  1
```

[Pic of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SZgb.png)

Lets say I have this table as shown above. I want to be able to average SELECTED values from column 2. Am I able to use any function in SSRS that allows me to select which value to use to average? The end goal is to allow the user to interactively choose which value to average.

For example if I would want to use `("Row 1 + Row 2 + Row 4")/3`, or `(Row 6 + Row 8)/2`, how can I go about letting the end user to choose those values to average?

Is there something that I need to do in SQL first to make it easier in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is by using report parameter and dataset filter

Add parameter in SSRS to allow user input of multiple values, set the available values for row-1, row-2, and so on

here for your reference how to add the parameter in SSRS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-change-or-delete-a-report-parameter-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=To%20add%20or%20edit%20a,or%20accept%20the%20default%20name.

after you add the parameter, let's say you already have a dataset which is SQL query such as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM the_table
```

Right click on your dataset, on properties, in the filter tab, add a filter for the column `ROW` IN parameter that you have made earlier

after you add filter on your dataset, on your report, simply use that dataset and put expression AVG(Column 2)